# After adding if condition, the toggle button stops to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/labuxuziraya/1/edit

After adding if condition, the button stops to work.
I am sure there is some minor bugs here but I am not that experienced enough to find that out.

Thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="div1 active">press outside the div to expand again</div>
<span class="btn btn-default">toggle to expand<span>
```

CSS

```
div {
background: lightgrey;
width: 200px;
height: 400px;
float: left;
padding: 15px;
margin: 15px;
}

.active {
   width: 50px;
 }
```

JS

```
function Trigger() {
 $('.div1').toggleClass('active');
 }


 $('.btn').on('click',function(){
   Trigger();
});


 $(document).click(function(event) { 
 if(!$(event.target).closest('.div1').length)
 {
     if( $('.div1').hasClass('active') )
    {Trigger();}        
  });
```

Comment: why do you want that if condition??

Comment: Indeed, I don't see the use of *that* if condition. Maybe you can explain some more what you want to achieve, then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and as Lal / LinkinTED commented, I think you can remove the
    `if( $('.div1').hasClass('active') )`
condition since it is handled in the `toggleClass` function.
So your easiest fix would be:

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.div1').length) {
        $('.div1').toggleClass('active');
    }        
});
```

If you stick with your condition, then you are basically reinventing the wheel (the toggle function) and you'd need to create `activate / deactivate` functions to call in your `if / else`:

```
function activate() {
     $('.div1').addClass("active");
}

function deactivate() {
     $('.div1').removeClass("active");
}

$(document).click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.div1').length) {
        if ( $('.div1').hasClass('active') ) {
            deactivate();
        }
        else {
            activate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Trigger() {
   $('.div1').toggleClass('active');
 }


 $('.btn').on('click',function(){
     Trigger();
 });

 $(document).click(function(event) {
 var target= event.target;

 //if they click anything but .div1, and .div1 is not expanded expand it.

 if(!$(target).hasClass('.div1') &&  !$('.div1').hasClass('active'))
      Trigger();
```